# Can or are G-suits ever used for non military applications?

Tags: equipment

I assume pressure suits are always used by astrounauts or high altitude jet aircraft. The g-suit has a different purpose, design and function. Other than dog fights are there any practical uses for g-suits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's G-suit, not g-suite. (Edited question). There's only room enough for one body in a suit.

Yes, counter-pressure suits, aka g-suits, have multiple applications. They are sometimes used medically, in particular for treating internal bleeding, but also a number of less common conditions.

These types of suits are useful in any aircraft that sustain low-pressure or high-g conditions. Most of these happen to be military, but any high-g maneuvering can benefit from the same. Racing pilots in the Red Bull wear them, for instance. Test pilots often do, particularly with high-altitude airplanes.

Another application is spacesuits. G-suits are worn during launches, which except for the Space Shuttle involve high g-loads. As of yet potential is their use for lightweight spacewalking suits.

Comment: Thank you for edit of my spelling error.

Comment: G-suite sounds like an exiting concept though 

Answer (score 2):

I recall that some of the Red Bull air race pilots made use of pneumatic anti-G suits when they flew, but, typically most civilian aerobatic pilots will fly maneuvers of up to +10/-7.5G without the use of anti-G suits.  Reciprocating engine powered aerobatic aircraft cannot maintain sustained high G loading for long before they are exhausted of energy, as opposed to the newer fighters like the F-22, which can sustain a 9G turn until either it runs out of gas, the pilot G-LOCs, or the right inceptor is released.

Civilian pilots flying experimental category surplus military jets in exhibitions (e.g. privately owned F-5s, T-38s, MiGs, etc) will use military issue anti-G suits as part of their flight gear and life support kit.

Answer (score 2):

Salyut space stations had a "negative g-suit" equipment that works exactly the opposite way, e.g. by pulling a vacuum on the legs simulate 1g in a 0g environment.

[Chibis vacuum suit](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780191842764.001.0001/acref-9780191842764-e-330)

> A Soviet *spacesuit introduced in 1978 for cosmonauts about to return from 126 days on the Salyut 6 space station mission. It was a low-pressure suit that forced the body's blood into the legs, an effect similar to that of Earth's gravity. This caused the cardiovascular system, slowed by weightlessness, to work harder and strengthen the heart in preparation for a return to gravity. Similar units were worn regularly by crews on the ... ...

Also there are other leg compression equipment for sustained standing and walking (1g for a long time is also a problem) e.g. compression socks and [compression leggings](http://www.90thidpg.us/Research/Original/M1938Leggings/index1.html). I think this one fits the question best because it is truly an anti-g equipment.

[image]

[Also there are IPC (Intermittent Pneumatic Compression) devices](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/treatments/14791-intermittent-pneumatic-compression-ipc-device)

> Intermittent pneumatic compression (IPC) devices are inflatable
> sleeves that prevent blood clots. You wear them on your calves (lower
> legs) to help your blood circulate. A plastic sleeve slides over and
> past each foot. Then, it goes around each calf and plugs into a small
> machine that makes it inflate.

[image]
[image source: amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09LCTXQB3)

Comment: Very interesting. I never thought of compression stockings something I  have to use myself everyday for edema. Uses the same concept Thank you for interesting research

Comment: Similar pneumatic compress leggings are often used after surgery. I know I had them for a couple of days after abdominal surgery. They are suppose to prevent blood clots in the legs  I think they also make them for shoulders and arms.